# Java Firewall Check? Tell the server admin to turn the firewall off

Tags: java, sockets, firewall

I'm building an application in which I am using Socket Programming in Java using TCP. When the server side Firewall  is running, I am unable to connect to the server. So how can I make a check in Java that the Firewall is running and tell the server administrator he should turn it off.

Comment: 'I am unable to bind with the server': you are unable to *connect to* the server?

Comment: I suggest you correct your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only guaranteed way of doing it is to actually try establishing a connection to the host:port.

But again, if you are unable to connect, you can't say that its because of firewall, it could be because of server being actually down. So you can't really tell with conformity that the firewall is turned on.

Comment: i know the port number!! i defined in my program can i use that?

Answer (score 1):

@Suraj is right. If you cannot to specific TCP port you do not know whether the host is unavailable, no one is listening to the port or firewall blocks you.
But there is a trick that helps in 90% of cases. 
Typically firewall configuration has exceptions like HTTP:80, ICMP etc. So, you can try to connect to your port. If it works, you are done. Otherwise try to perform any other connection to the host (HTTP, ICMP etc.) If you managed to do this firewall blocked you. Otherwise probably the host is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but in general the only reliable way to see if any resource is available is to try to use it. You have to cope with the exceptions that arise anyway, and using some other test prior to the real attempt isn't guaranteed to exercise the same paths and introduces a timing-window problem. So don't do it. Just write the code and catch the exceptions.